# how to write dsl condition with null check

Tags: drools

we have .dsl file with below entry

```
[condition][]residence duration >\= {value}=FamilyMember(basicInfo.permanentResidenceDuration >= {value})
```

Now this basicInfo.permanentResidenceDuration is coming out to be null in beginning. Can anyboy help me out how to write the state which satisfy the following condition. If basicInfo.permanentResidenceDuration == null assign 0 else the value of basicInfo.permanentResidenceDuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you need, but why not simply do something like this?

```
[condition][]residence duration >\= {value}=FamilyMember(basicInfo.permanentResidenceDuration != null && >= {value})
```

Comment: what will happen if the value basicInfo.permanentResidenceDuration == null? will it work?

Comment: the condition is testing for a non-null value, so if it is null, it will just not match.